# how interface will hide the implemenation details

Tags: java, interface

May be this is a little novice question. I always heard people saying interface will hide the implementation details.I can't able to understand what does that mean in a specific way.I will tell what i understood till now.Please Tell me if there is any wrong in my understanding.

Let us suppose, We have a `List` interface declared like this in our code.

```
    List ls= new ArrayList()
```

By changing above line like

```
   ArrayList ls= new ArrayList();
```

I can see every implementation details of `ArrayList` by Ctrl+click on the methods in my IDE.

If you declare `ls` as a private variable in a class and only giving `getter` to that variable will return reference of interface. In that way you don't know what Object that reference is pointing out.In that way you can hide implementation details.

I think there is more to it than this.Please give me more clarity on this one.

**Edit:-** I know how polymorphism works through interface.My doubt is Hiding implementation details means literally hiding or it means the End user doesn't need to bother about implementation details of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is not really, but... 
The good thing about hiding is, that it is possible to switch the List implementation (ArrayList) by, lets say, BetterList without breaking the getter. The internal BetterList could then have some features, wich should not be exposed.
Further, the BetterList could implement more than one interface (List and some "ElevatedList" for example). So you could expose 2 getters for different use cases pointing to the same object, but different interfaces.

For example:

```
public  class MyObject {
static class BetterList extends ArrayList<String>{
     void someInternalLogic(){
        //
    }
}
private BetterList internalList1=new BetterList();
public List<String> getList1(){
    internalList1.someInternalLogic();
    return internalList1;
}


private List internalList2=new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> getList2(){
    return internalList2;
}
```

}

The getList1-getter hides the someInternalLogic method from external user behind the List interface, wich may be useful, if execution of that method should be controlled internally. The getList2-getter hides the ArrayList-Type behind the List interface leaving the freedom to change the implementation of the internalList2 to f.e. LinkedList, wich may be prefered later.

Comment: I'm not asking about polymorphism.I want to know can it really hide the implementation details in any way other than that or is there any different context to hiding implementation details.

Comment: @udaybhaskar No, that's what hiding implementation details means. You have the interface (or API) that is seen externally, and the implementation is something that the caller shouldn't care about. Mikey's answer explains how it works in a real life situation.

Comment: @Mikey Can you elaborate little more.I'm having trouble understanding your answer. With some proper sample code or some links to the Explanation.

Comment: @udaybhaskar Example added.

Comment: @Mikey Now i got to know actually hiding implementation details means not literally **keeping secret** . Just interface will put the details **behind it** , so author can change anytime and user don't need to bother about it. Thanks .

Comment: @udaybhaskar my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

The key word here with the concept of "hiding the implementation" is flexibility because the only constant on software development is called **CHANGE**. If you are chained to a concrete class behavior the evolution of your code is harder. When your are programming to the interface the user really don't care about the implementation details. So about literally "hiding" in your IDE you can see all the implementations to that interface pressig `CTRL+T` over the interface name (at least on eclipse).